# Android studio , List View, java

Tags: java, android-studio, listview, arraylist

The app is keeps crashing , what can I do?
this is the code:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        ListView TestListView = findViewById(R.id.ListView1);
        final ArrayList<String> TestObjects = new ArrayList<String>(asList("PC" , "Phone"));
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this , android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,TestObjects);
        TestListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    }
}
```

Comment: The id should not be in capital letters. change your R.id.ListView1 to R.id.list_view both in your xml and java code.

Answer (score 0):

this is my code,it can work.

```
String[] Balls= new String[] {"ball","pen","toy","other"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.ex_list_view01);

    lstPrefer=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstPrefer);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapterBalls=new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,Balls);

    lstPrefer.setAdapter(adapterBalls);  


    lstPrefer.setOnItemClickListener(lstPreferListener);
}
```